# TCP reset recorded on JPOS server

Tags: java, iso8583, jpos

I have set up a JPOS server to receive messages. I noticed recently that after a brief period of inactivity, we start realizing `TCP RESET FROM SERVER` errors

See below my configuration for the channel

```xml
<channel name="post-channel" class="org.jpos.iso.channel.PostChannel">
    <property name="packager-realm" value="postpack-debug" />
    <property name="keep-alive" value="true" />
</channel>
```

Answer (score 0):

The other end is probably not liking the `keep alive` sent by your channel, just disable that by commenting out that line.

If you`re using that keep alive to keep the channel connected without ending because of timeout, you should send` 0800` network messages at regular intervals.

While developing, you can disable that timeout from your side by setting the `timeout` property to zero (the default is, 30000 seconds = 5 minutes):

```xml
<property name="timeout" value="0"/>
```

But you don't want that in a production environment.

Comment: Exactly - you definitely want to have a timeout

https://jpos.org/blog/2014/04/you-want-a-timeout/